# Display a specific element from a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am struggling to display a specific element from my JavaScript object. My code below shows my attempt.

```
import React from 'react';

const pgnParser = require('pgn-parser');

const [result] = pgnParser.parse(
  '[White "me"]\n[Black "you"]\n1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bc4 Bc5 (3. ...Nf6 {is the two knights}) 4. b4 Bxb4 5. c3 Ba5 6. d4 exd4 7. O-O Nge7 $1 *'
);

console.log(result);

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Hello world</h1>
      <p>{result[0][moves][0]}</p>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The pgnParser code has the data in this format:

```
[
    {
        headers: [ 
            {name: "White", value: "me"},
            {name: "Black", value: "you"}
        ],
        result: "*",
        moves: [
            { move: 'e4', move_number: 1},
            { move: 'e5'},
            { move: 'Nf3', move_number: 2},
            { move: 'Nc6'},
            { move: 'Bc4', move_number: 3},
            { move: 'Bc5', ravs: [{ moves: [{move_number: 3, move: "...Nf6", comments: [{text: "is the two knights"}]}]}]},
            { move: 'b4', move_number: 4},
            { move: 'Bxb4'},
            { move: 'c3', move_number: 5},
            { move: 'Ba5'},
            { move: 'd4', move_number: 6},
            { move: 'exd4'},
            { move: 'O-O', move_number: 7},
            { move: 'Nge7', nags: ["$1"]}
        ]
    }
]
```

I've looked at JSON.stringify, but if I am correct, the format above is not actually JSON. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Any ideas on how to display, for example, the move e5? How do I reference that and display to the screen? I can then work out the loop for what I want to do myself.

The console log shows this array output:

```
{comments_above_header: null, headers: Array(2), comments: null, moves: Array(14), result: "*"}
comments: null
comments_above_header: null
headers: (2) [{…}, {…}]
moves: Array(14)
0: {move_number: 1, move: "e4", comments: Array(0)}
1: {move: "e5", comments: Array(0)}
2: {move_number: 2, move: "Nf3", comments: Array(0)}
3: {move: "Nc6", comments: Array(0)}
4: {move_number: 3, move: "Bc4", comments: Array(0)}
5: {move: "Bc5", ravs: Array(1), comments: Array(0)}
6: {move_number: 4, move: "b4", comments: Array(0)}
7: {move: "Bxb4", comments: Array(0)}
8: {move_number: 5, move: "c3", comments: Array(0)}
9: {move: "Ba5", comments: Array(0)}
10: {move_number: 6, move: "d4", comments: Array(0)}
11: {move: "exd4", comments: Array(0)}
12: {move_number: 7, move: "O-O", comments: Array(0)}
13: {move: "Nge7", nags: Array(1), comments: Array(0)}
length: 14
__proto__: Array(0)
result: "*"
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: `result[0].moves[0].move`

Comment: it is not a valid json. Try to use https://jsonlint.com/ to validate your json object.

Comment: According to https://www.npmjs.com/package/pgn-parser the output should be a valid JS Object, but it is not. Jon, did you post an actual product of the parser or is it just the example? Because it looks like the official example and it might as well just contain unnoticed typos (see the e5 thing)

Comment: The output I posted above is taken from what was shown on their page here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pgn-parser

Comment: posting the result of  `console.log(result)` would be helpful, also what does the browser console show as errors. (obviously your syntax for trying to get what you want is wrong as well)

Comment: The error shown is " Failed to compile: Line 15:21:  'moves' is not defined  no-undef"

Comment: ok seeing the result of the console log you should be doing: `result.moves[1].move` to get `e5` aka `<p>{result.moves[1].move}</p>`

Comment: `let e5 = result.moves.find(move => move.move === 'e5')` Not sure how you want to "display that to the screen". That's up to you.

Comment: @azium Thank you for your suggest, which worked! `<p>{result.moves[1].move}</p>` correctly displayed e5 and I can work everything else out from there. If I end up with 100 items in this array, do I then use this instead? `<p>{result[5].moves[1].move}</p>` to get the 6th game in the array?

Comment: `result` is not an array, so no

Answer (score 0):

This isn't valid JSON. There's just a curly brace missing after the comma here `{ move: 'e5',`

Once you fix that, it's valid JSON and you can reference and loop through it as you normally would.

I just used an online JSON Formatter to check your format. You could probably use an inbuilt tool or plugin from the IDE you're using.

Comment: if it weren't valid JSON the the function wouldn't return an object that could be referenced, either way it's not an issue with OP's code

Comment: I think the issue might be that I copy and pasted the example on the npm page, but they have a typo. I will edit my original post.

Comment: @Jon are you running the example given on their npm page? Because ```result``` is an object and not an Array. So if you do ```console.log(result['moves'][0])``` that would print the first element inside ```moves```. I just tried it out.

Comment: Yes, I am running their example. I thought `result` was an array because it was set equal to something with brackets around it [ ]. Or, am I wrong here because it is destructured and I have misunderstood destructing?

Comment: When you use ```[result] = [1,2,3]``` to destructure an array, ```result``` contains the first element in the array. Which is 1 in this case. In your case, the first element inside the array returned by ```pgnParser.parse``` is an object and that's why ```result``` is an object.